# Pure CSS: Center Tooltip Above Text On Hover

Tags: css

Fiddle to see what I have so far: http://jsbin.com/udegux/1/edit

HTML

```
<span id="test" class="drag-hint"><span>drag</span>Mouse and drag</span>
```

CSS:

```
.drag-hint {
  position:relative;
}
.drag-hint > span{
  display:none;
}
.drag-hint:hover > span {
  display:inline;
  position:absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 30px;
}
```

As you can see, I am currently manually centering the hover drag tip over the text by specifying the "top" and "left" attributes.  If the text was longer or shorter, I would have to manually change those values to make the tip look centered.

I am looking for a way to automatically center the word "drag" above the phrase "Mouse and drag" using pure CSS.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you position the block on top of the text and above and set `text-align: center`, there shouldn't be any need to use JavaScript.

```
.drag-hint:hover > span {
  display: inline;
  position:absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

[JSBin](http://jsbin.com/idudal/1/).

Comment: Works perfectly.  Can you explain what is happening when you set both left and right to 0?

Comment: nvm, found the answer to my own question [here](http://alistapart.com/article/conflictingabsolutepositions): The two 0 values stretch the box to be as wide as the parent, and the text-align:center centers it within that stretched box.

Comment: Hi! Really nice, but what if the tooltip is wider than its container? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292600/pure-css-center-tooltip-above-text-on-hover-pt-2

Answer (score 8):

More dynamic solution:

```css
.tooltip--top {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: calc(100% + 5px);
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%);
}
```

The 5px is offset from the top edge of the parent element. Usual stuff.