# Pure CSS: Center Tooltip Above Text On Hover pt. 2

Tags: css

Expanding on [Pure CSS: Center Tooltip Above Text On Hover](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16754726/pure-css-center-tooltip-above-text-on-hover) -- **how does one make the tooltip hover centered relative to its container if the tooltip is wider than said container?**

http://jsbin.com/idudal/24/edit

Ie. this (where `drag drag drag` gets cut off):

[image]

Should appear as:

[image]

HTML:

```
<span id="test" class="drag-hint"><span>drag drag drag drag drag</span>Hover me</span>
```

CSS:

```
.drag-hint {
  position:relative;
  margin: 50px;
}
.drag-hint > span {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display:none;
}
.drag-hint:hover > span {
  display: inline;
  position:absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Please put your code in your question, don't make us go looking for it.

Comment: What do you want it to do?

Comment: I forgot. Don't give me an attitude @JonP.

Comment: Can we change the HTML if needed?

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Here's the simplest solution using CSS3 transform.

[**JSfiddle Demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/k8h8a60b/2/)

```css
.drag-hint {
  position: relative;
  margin: 50px;
  display: inline-block;
  padding: 0 1em;
  border: 1px solid red;
  /* for visual reference */
}
.drag-hint > span {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  white-space: nowrap;
  display: none;
}
.drag-hint:hover > span {
  display: inline-block;
  position: absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<span class="drag-hint">
    <span>drag drag drag drag drag</span>
Hover me</span>


<span class="drag-hint">
    <span>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit.</span>
Hover me</span>
```

Comment: By far the most eleegant solution. Big ups to ya!

Answer (score 1):

Try with modified below code in your code.

```
.drag-hint:hover > span {
  display: inline;
  position:absolute;
  top: -25px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
  width:200px;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, there should be no fixed widths though as the length of the tooltips may change.

Answer (score 1):

[**JS Bin**](http://jsbin.com/lareguyejeti/1/edit)

```
 .drag-hint:hover > span {
    display: table;
    position: absolute;
    top: -25px;
    left: -51px;
    right: 0;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 2px;
 }
```

Comment: Sorry, there should be no fixed positions as the widths of the tooltips as well as their containers may change. Ie. http://twitter.com/

Answer (score 1):

## [JS Bin](http://jsbin.com/riyavajejeqo/1/edit)

I achieve your question.

## HTML

```
<h1>This:</h1>
    <div id="test" class="drag-hint"><p>drag drag drag drag drag</p>Hover me</div>
    <h1>Should appear as:</h1>
    <img src="http://s22.postimg.org/h1qk194bh/Untitled_2.jpg">
```

## CSS

```
.drag-hint {
  position:relative;
  margin: 50px;
}
.drag-hint > p {
  background: black;
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
 display: none;
}
.drag-hint:hover > p {
  display: inline;
  position:absolute;
  top: -40px;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: Sorry, but the tool tip is not centered.

Comment: Better but I doubt the full width background is desired.

Comment: Nice, but as @JonP pointed out we might need to change the HTML as it needs something relative to center itself to, yeah? http://jsbin.com/riyavajejeqo/1/edit

Comment: @MarkBoulder Like this? http://jsbin.com/fisapuluxuje/1/edit       There are too many ways to achieve your purpose.

Comment: Looks pretty neat. I think I'll go with that one. Cheers mate!

Answer (score 0):

Use div instead of span

```
<div id="test" class="drag-hint"><div>drag drag drag drag drag</div>Hover me</div>
```

[a fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/mj3y0dxu/3/)

Comment: Sorry, but the tool tip is not centered. Refer to the image in the question.

Comment: @JonP why the downvote? Im sorry because the image seems to be incorrect path in jsbin...

Comment: Did you read my comment? THat is why the down vote, the tool tip should be centered on the target, not left aligned.

Comment: @JonP so you saw the time when my answer and your comment posted..?

Comment: @HTTP for what it's worth I upvoted you - thanks a lot man :)

Answer (score 0):

I hope this will solve your problem.
http://jsbin.com/xihupeyowize/1/