# Pure CSS: Center Tooltip Above Text On Hover pt. 3

Tags: html, css

Expanding on [Pure CSS: Center Tooltip Above Text On Hover pt. 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292600/pure-css-center-tooltip-above-text-on-hover-pt-2) by Mark Boulder.

I need to do the exact same thing, except my tooltip is under the text and can't be `white-space: nowrap`: I just want to define a constant `max-width` for the tooltip, which would then adapt its size to its content, until it reaches this value and displays on more lines.

What I have:

[image]

What I need:

Thinner than parent \ \ \ \ \ Larger than parent \ \ \ \ \ Breaks line when reaches max-width
[image]

CSS:

```css
    .drag-hint {
      position: relative;
      margin: 20px 80px;
      display: inline-block;
      padding: 0 1em;
      border: 1px solid red;
    }
    .drag-hint > span {
      background: black;
      color: white;
      display: none;
    }
    .drag-hint:hover > span {
      max-width: 160px; /* useless for now */
      display: inline-block;
      position: absolute;
      top: 25px;
      left: 50%;
      transform: translateX(-50%);
    }
```

```html
    <span class="drag-hint">
        <span>Blah.</span>
        Hover me
    </span>

    <span class="drag-hint">
        <span>Blah blah blah blah.</span>
        Hover me
    </span>

    <span class="drag-hint">
        <span>Blah blah blah blah blah blah blah.</span>
        Hover me
    </span>
```

Can you see a pure HTML/CSS solution?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `flexbox`? I haven't done much with tooltips but I love flexbox for centering things that don't want to be centered. https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/ is a great place to get the basics quickly if you aren't familiar. Something like

```
.drag-hint {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
};
```

might be all you need.

Comment: Thanks for the reply! I'm not used to using flexbox for this kind of problems... It might be the best way to do it, I can't make it work though :3

Answer (score 0):

Got it - the reason the text is showing up in a column like that is because of your `inline-block`. Inline-block elements don't have a width unless you explicitly set one. You can solve that by just adding `width: 100%;` to the hover rule, which overrides that issue.

Comment: `width: 100%;` forces the tooltip to be the exact same size as its parent ; in my problem, the tooltip must sometimes be thinner than the text (when it contains a short string), but can also be larger (its `max-width` is larger than the parent's content). Thanks for your time though, I appreciate!