# trouble creating a tooltip

Tags: html, css, reactjs

**Objective:** I am trying to create a tooltip where if you hover over a text a tooltip should appear. Basically, I would like to recreate this example at w3schools. Here is the link https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_css_tooltip.

**My Code:**

```
render() {
        return (
            <div >
                <h2>Tooltip</h2>
                <p>Move the mouse over the text below:</p>

                <div class = "tooltip">
                    Hover over me 
                    // <img src = "assets/images/react.png" alt="React / React Native" className = "icons"></img>

                    <span class = "tooltiptext">
                        Tooltip text 
                    </span>
                </div>
            </div>
            

        );
    }
```

```
.tooltip {
  position: relative;
  display: inline-block;
  border-bottom: 1px dotted black;
}

 .tooltip, .tooltiptext {
  visibility: hidden;
  width: 120px;
  background-color: #555;
  color: black;
  text-align: center;
  border-radius: 6px;
  padding: 5px 0;
  position: relative;
  right: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  /* bottom: 125%; */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -60px;
  opacity: 0;
  transition: opacity 0.3s;
}

.tooltip, .tooltiptext::after {
  content: "";
  position: absolute;
  /* top: 100%; */
  left: 50%;
  margin-left: -5px;
  border-width: 5px;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #555 transparent transparent transparent;
}

.tooltip:hover, .tooltiptext {
  visibility: visible;
  opacity: 1;
}
```

side-note: I'm aware I commented out some positioning styles in the CSS so it is easier to find. Also, I would prefer to hover over a tech icon and have it display its name, but first I thought it would be better to start simple.

**Outcome:** The "Hover Over me" text and tooltip do not display; it appears white so you can't see it. However, If I hover over the tooltip text, both elements display. I can figure out the position of these elements through developer tools. Also, the tooltip does not display properly.

[image: Here is a link to the picture]

Comment: Just a heads up, you should be using [`className`](https://reactjs.org/docs/faq-styling.html) instead of `class` when setting class attribute in JSX.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using the wrong CSS selectors. You want to use `.tooltip .tooltiptext` instead of `.tooltip, .tooltiptext` (no comma) and similar for the other rules. The first one selects elements with the class `.tooltiptext` that are descendants of `.tooltip`. The second one selects elements that have the class `.tooltip` or `.tooltiptext`.

[Documentation](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css_selectors.asp)

Comment: thanks, but I already tried that and it still doesn't work. When I do the way you mentioned, nothing even appears when I hover over it. However, when I go on developer tools, I can still see the elements are still there...

Comment: Could you create a codesandbox and share the link?

Comment: Here's a [working version](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-tdd-lj184?file=/src/App.tsx) with the commas removed. Maybe you can compare it to what you have to see if anything is different. The styles are in [`styles.css`](https://codesandbox.io/s/focused-tdd-lj184?file=/src/styles.css).

Comment: I'm not sure why, but your working version doesn't work for me. Here is my "working" version but it's still not exactly correct but a lot closer than the one in my current react project. https://codesandbox.io/s/tooltip-u4m9x?file=/src/styles.css.

Comment: Also, do you know if putting your css elements in your app.css rather than styles.css makes a difference? I'm not sure if its just different names, but I see a lot of people use styles.css instead

Comment: They're just being imported globally in App.js, so it doesn't really matter. There's another thing called [CSS modules](https://create-react-app.dev/docs/adding-a-css-modules-stylesheet/) which have to be named a certain way though.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm having difficulty aligning the tooltip. Perhaps [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26292600/pure-css-center-tooltip-above-text-on-hover-pt-2) will help you if you want to center it.